# Create AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an Aler Dialog but when I click on button my application crash.Any idea what's happening and how can I fix that?

Here is the code :

```
    Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
    deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder( MyCollectionId.this )
            .setTitle( "Invalid selection" )
            .setMessage( "Drbr" )
            .setPositiveButton( "Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                }
            })
            .show();    

        }

    });
```

LogCat :

```
08-08 11:51:39.794: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44c1d9f0 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:468)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.MyCollectionId$3.onClick(MyCollectionId.java:67)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-08 11:51:39.824: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(551):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder( MyCollectionId.this )
```

is setting the context for your dialog to attach to the activity.

You either need to use

```
 YourActivity.this

 new AlertDialog.Builder( YourActivity.this )
```

or set the context to a variable and use that:

```
 Context mContext;

 onCreate(){
   mContext = this;
 }

 yourOnClick{
   new AlertDialog.Builder( mContext )
 }
```

If this isn't your issue you need more 'context' around your question, where are you calling the dialog from what Activity are you in what is the state of Activity.

Comment: Actually I realize that I can't use context = this; in my situation,because I forgot to mention that my Activity is part of TabGroupActivity,so I need to replace content=this; with getParent() and everything works fine! Thanks for helping me to realize that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1=new AlertDialog.Builder(MyAlertdialogActivity.this);
builder1.setMessage("Please Press Ok");
builder1.setNeutralButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ok is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  });
builder1.show();
```

Do check my humble blog too if you find it useful..I've have discussed about AlertDialog in detail there:
http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/01/25/dialog/